# jQuery trying to get value of input results are undefined

Tags: html, jquery

I think I must be missing something but have not been able to figure it out. For the `var fname` I am getting undefined but it should be the value of `f_name`. Why is this not working? I did try to switch `('.f_name').val()` to be `('.f_name').attr('value')` but that did not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.include').change(function() {
    var s_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('value');
    var fname = $(this).closest('.f_name').val();
    var flexcheck = $(this).hasClass('ss');
    var e_group = $(this).val();
    alert(fname);
    if (e_group != '' & flexcheck == false) {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('#fCheck').prop('checked', true);
      $("select").append("<option value='" + s_id + "'>" + s_id + +fname + "</option>");
      $(this).closest('tr').find("td.hl").addClass('bg-warning');
      $(this).closest('input.include').addClass('ss');
    } else if (e_group == '' & flexcheck == true) {
      $(this).closest('input.ss').removeClass('ss');
      $(this).closest('tr').find('#fCheck').prop('checked', false);
      $("select option[value='" + s_id + "']").remove();
      $(this).closest('tr').find("td.hl").removeClass('bg-warning');

    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 4%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#transparent {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="col-8">
    <table id="table" class="sg_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="tt1">id
          </th>
          <th class="tt1">First Name
          </th>
          <th style="display:none;">hidden
          </th>
          <th class="tt1">E Group
          </th>
          <th class="tt1">Follows
          </th>

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr id="IN" name="id" value="CA17_001_001">
          <td style="display:none;" class="draggable">Clark</td>
          <td>001_001<input id="transparent" type="hidden" name="id" value="CA17_001_001"></td>
          <td><input id="transparent" class="f_name" type="textarea" name="name" value="Clark"></td>
          <td style="display:none;"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="CA17_001_001" id="fCheck" name="include"></td>
          <td class="hl"><input id="transparent" class="include" type="text" name="e_group" value=""></td>
          <td class="hl">
            <select name="flow_to" id="flow_to">
              <option value="start">start</option>
            </select>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="TP" name="id" value="CA17_002_002">
          <td style="display:none;" class="draggable">Christian</td>
          <td>002_002<input id="transparent" type="hidden" name="id" value="CA17_002_002"></td>
          <td><input id="transparent" class="f_name" type="textarea" name="name" value="Christian"></td>
          <td style="display:none;"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="CA17_002_002" id="fCheck" name="include"></td>
          <td class="hl"><input id="transparent" class="include" type="text" name="e_group" value=""></td>
          <td class="hl">
            <select name="flow_to" id="flow_to">
              <option value="start">start</option>

            </select>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi , change this to `$(this).closest('.f_name').val()` to `$(this).closest('tr').find('.f_name').val()` .

Comment: `closest()` only will traverse upward to its parents, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on. Your `f_name` is a child within a `<tr>`. You will the the code provided by @Swati

Comment: @Swati, Thank you for the comment. I have tried this and it is working.

Comment: @JoshuaOoi thank you for the comment. You have a typo (in the last sentence) of your comment and I don't understand what you are saying.